# How to correctly compare 2 correlation values using the Fisher r-to-z transform?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, fisher-transform

In https://www.statisticshowto.com/fisher-z/, it is stated that “But it’s probably most commonly be used to test the significance of the difference between two correlation coefficients, r1 and r2 from independent samples. If r1 is larger than r2, the z-value will be positive; If r1 is smaller than r2, the z-value will be negative”.

How can I do this? If I have r1 and r2, I first convert them individually to a z-score and then subtract the z-score values? Or I do r1-r2 and apply the transform on this output?

Comment: First transform the two correlations $r_1$ and $r_2$ into two approximately normal random variables $z_1$ and $z_2$. Then compute statistic for the difference of two normals. Keep in mind that $z_1$ and $z_2$ have difference standard deviations unless the sample sizes are the same.

Comment: thanks. in [this](https://garstats.wordpress.com/2019/06/17/compindcorr/), section "Procedure", do the formulas seem right?